# how can i use a helper in different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

i am using refinery cms at the moment. I created an engine and with it some helpers in `app/helpers/admin/`.
now i would like to use those helpers in my frontend view (ie. `app/views/myapp/index`) as well. but i can not...undefined methode error.
what do i have to do short of copying the whole thing to `app/helpers/`?
the helper looks like this

```
module Admin
    module myHelper
        def somefunc
        end
    end
end
```

so is it possible to use `somefunc` outside of the Admin module?

Comment: +1 good question. I struggled with this for a few minutes last night before bed. Nice to come in and find the exact question/answer I was looking for...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your `application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Admin::MyHelper
end
```

This will import those helper methods into the `ApplicationHelper`, thus making them available in your views.  You could do this in any of your helpers really.

Comment: Thanks that works. But why does it not work when i just include it in MyHelper...like this
`module MyHelper include Admin::MyHelper` why do i have to go over application_helpers when it is in the same engine?

Comment: Rails doesn't include any view helper modules deeper than the top-level namespace, you need to include them yourself.

Comment: Hmm, where is `my_helper.rb` ?

Comment: ahh allright i found the error in my head. thanks a lot for clearing that up...have a great day!

Comment: @d11wtq: Your second comment points at the origin of the problem, could you add it to the answer? thanks.

Comment: What if I want to incude just a single method from the helper?

Answer (score 63):

The "Rails way" to include a helper from a non-standard path in a view is to use the .helper method within your controller.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    helper Admin::MyHelper
    ...
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much better than globally including the helper.

Comment: Very nice. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the full object reference like `Admin::myHelper::somefunc` to call `somefunc` from outside the `Admin` module.